# Ruby Error: wrong number of arguments (given 4, expected 0) (ArgumentError)

Tags: ruby

I am a ruby beginner and I am trying to make a method called print that prints all the elements in a given array. I want my code to get an undefined local variable error.

This is what I got from Youtube. This gives an undefined local variable error.

```
movies = ["good","bad"]

def good_movies
    movies.each do |movies|
        puts "I like #{movie}"
    end
end

good_movies
```

I am using interactive Ruby. This is my version.

```
numbers = [1,2,3]

def print
    numbers.each do |number|
        puts "#{number}"
    end
end

print
```

I am getting an error: (irb):2:in `print': wrong number of arguments (given 4, expected 0) (ArgumentError). Why am I getting this, not the undefined local variable error?

What is going on?

Comment: Try to avoid method names that override `Kernel` methods (such as `print` etc). The second issue @Paul Ro pointed below.

Comment: You are right. I solved it by changing the method name.

Comment: did you paste the correct error message?

Comment: You have to define a parameter in your method, then pass an enumerable as an argument when calling the method.

Answer (score 5):

You have to pass an argument 'numbers" to the `print` method.

```
numbers = [1,2,3]

def print(nums)
    nums.each do |number|
        puts number
    end
end
```

And then:

```
print(numbers)
```